# Why do Pillagers keep spawning near my singleplayer Minecraft house? Is there anything I can do about it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Usually while I'm in my Minecraft house, Pillagers keep spawning near my Minecraft house! Let me give you a little info on where I live, I live by the riverside, if you go along the right side of the lake, you'll reach a Village! But you can only see a bit of the Village from my Minecraft house if you set the render distance on maximum.

Comment: @fasterthanlight Not a duplicate because this is Java Edition and that is Bedrock Edition.

Comment: @pppery Oops, forgot to read the tags, retracting close vote.

Answer (score 11):

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Patrol#Java_Edition):

> Patrols can spawn during the day on blocks with a block light level of 7 or lower. If a player is within two chunks of a village, patrols do not spawn.
>
> The game picks a random location 24–48 blocks away from the player to try to spawn the patrol's captain.

Additionally, in bedrock there are additional location where Illager (patrols) *can* spawn, where other mobs cannot - this includes the river biome, but I am not certain how this works in Java.

You can check around the area where they normally spawn and see if there are any cave entrances nearby. Using <kbd>F3</kbd> you can see the "light level" that a block has.

[image: screenshot of example]

Answer (score 6):

That's natural for Pillagers. They're meant to spawn randomly so you can get village bonuses and start raids. Light level means nothing in this scenario as they are an overworld mob. All they do naturally is come out and attack at random points, just like Wandering Traders spawn randomly. The best you could do is fight them off, but there is, sadly, no solution besides redstone traps.

EDIT:

> Pillagers continually spawn in a 72×54×72 block volume centered on the top floor. They may spawn on any valid opaque block as long as the sky light level is 11 or lower, and the block light level is 8 or lower, **but can also spawn on grass or sand blocks regardless of block light level**.

Love, the official Minecraft Wiki. **This disproves the light level theorum.**

They spawn on all grass and sand, regardless of light level. Blocking it up with torches is not only a waste of materials, but ineffective as well. They will spawn in any of the 5184 blocks of dirt around your base. Place a crap-ton of netherrack or something around your base, but I doubt you could block the 5184 blocks you would have to place around your base you would need to prevent them from spawning. Just deal with it at this point. I would take pillager raids as awesome because they give you free stuff.

Comment: Light level does matter, place lots of torches around your base and you see that you never get attacked by pillagers. Pillagers only look at block light, they ignore skylight only

Comment: "Pillagers continually spawn in a 72×54×72 block volume centered on the top floor. They may spawn on any valid opaque block as long as the sky light level is 11 or lower, and the block light level is 8 or lower, **but can also spawn on grass or sand blocks regardless of block light level** ." Pillager - Minecraft Wiki. Screw it this is going in my answer.